# Read arbitrary number of objects from a binary file

Tags: java, io, binaryfiles

Ok so I have an 'Animal' class that is abstract with subclasses 'Dog' and 'Bird' I need to write a program to read and unknown number of Animal objects from a binary file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    readAnimals("birdsAndDogs.dat");

}

public static List<Animal> readAnimals(String filename) {
    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));

        try {
            while (true) {
                Animal a =(Animal) ois.readObject();

                if (a instanceof Animal)
                    animals.add((Animal)a);
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
        catch (EOFException eof) {
            ois.close();
            ois = null;
            return animals;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}   
}
```

This is my first time trying to read binary files, so take it easy, the code may be pretty messy I'm not sure but my main problem is I keep getting a FileNotFoundExeption, but the file is in the same package and location, any ideas?

also is the code it self structured correctly?

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application sees

```
new FileInputStream("justADog.dat")
```

it looks for the file name in the directory the application was launched from. I very much doubt your application was ran from the package your class is in.

Either provide a full path to the file or move the file to the location your application is ran from. With Eclipse, the application is started from your project folder.

Comment: they are in the same project folder, also when I get the full path from properties I still have same problem.

Comment: The binary files i'm trying to test and all the classes

Comment: Please read the answer carefully. Assuming you are on Eclipse, move the `binary` files to the root of the project. Leave the `.java` files in their respective packages.

Comment: ok yes I see, sorry i'm new to eclipse is the src folder used as root?

Comment: @user2745043 `src` folder is used to hold that files that you expect to find in your application's classpath (what eclipse calls the build path). Put the `.dat` file in the Project (whatever your project is called) folder.

Comment: Ok thanks that fixed the problem of the FileNotFoundException, however now I'm not getting an output, am I not reading the file in correctly? or not printing it correctly?

Comment: @user2745043 It doesn't seem like you are calling the method.

Comment: sorry first time using this, can you give a little more detail? thanks

Comment: @User In the code you've shown, your `main()` method  isn't calling your `readAnimals` method.

Comment: Oh yea, it's been a long night missing the simple stuff, forgive me lol. Ok the program works great, thanks, one more thing since you're being so helpful, in the code I have the 'fileName' is in 3 places, what would be the simplest way, if there is one, to just have it 1 time? Should FileInputStream fstream be in readAnimals()?

Comment: @user Yes. First there's no point having the `fstream` declaration in your `main()` method as it stand since you don't use it. When you call `readAnimals()` you pass the name of the file as an argument. That value is bound to the `filename` parameter. Use that when creating the `FileInputStream`, ie. `new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));`

Comment: Ok, was thinking it should be something like that just wasn't sure what. Thanks for all your help, I've posted the updated code and seems to be working great, does it seem anything needs to be changed or tips when doing this in the future? I'm beginning program so taking all the tips and advice